# Placing image in imageview from URL without image extension (Android)

Tags: android, url, imageview

I have an image stored at the following [URL](https://g8usa.g8.net:443/lo/g8_cfdb/g8_cfdb_device_img_decode.php?g8_cfdb_unique_id=10005)

And I would like to extract the image from this URL and place it in an ImageView. I have tried using Picasso and also tried using Bitmap but it doesn't seem to work. 
How should I go about achieving this task?

```
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
Picasso.with(this).load(url).into(myImageView);
```

The internet permission is granted. 
The URL loads on the net and I can see the image.

Comment: post your code here

Comment: `it doesn't seem to work` the only thing it means is that you used it incorrectly. Show how you used it, and we'll help to correct your code.

Comment: Picasso load only images not html page

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code:

```
ImageView thumbNail;

For Loading Image in Imageview ,

Picasso.with(activity).load(url).noFade().into(thumbNail);
```

Answer (score 0):

With Picasso or Glide you can load the imageUrl into the ImageView easily like,

```
`Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);`
```

But even after you followed this and still it doesn't work in the sense. try out the following possibilities.

1.Check whether the Internet Permission is given in the android manifest.

2.Check whether the URL is accessible from the internet or the network that who have connected to by hitting the url in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The URL which you have posted do not return an image. It return HTML code with Image data.

```
<img src="Image Data"  height="100%" width="100%"  alt="No image in db">
```

This type of response only work in browser or WebView.

Now the easy way would be ask your backend guy to give the image path or data directly so that you can use Picasso or Glide library directly.

And the other way would be you create a custom ImageLoader class where you call the url, extract the image data from the response string and convert into a Bitmap and apply to ImageView.